# What is the right path for PHP includes on a Mac?

Tags: php, macos, include, server-side-includes, include-path

Running Mac OS X 10.5.8, with PHP 5.2.11 Pre-installed. Using Coda 1.6.10.

I'm writing PHP files, and then preview them running from file, not server. This was working fine till I tried PHP includes. These don't work as a relative path, only as an absolute from the root of the drive.

Is there any way I can use statements like

> include_once "common/header.php";

without specifying my entire file path like so :

> include_once "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/neil/Desktop/Website/ColoredLists_v1.0/common/base.php";

,where ColoredLists_v1.0 is the directory with all the website files in it. I tried solutions like prepending _SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] or dirname(**File**) to the file paths, but that didn't work as the variables were not set. Is there any easy way to do this, or a configuration I can change so that it looks in a specific directory by default instead of looking at the drive root? Currently, echo_include_path shows .:

When I include this line at the start of the script, it works:

> set_include_path('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/neil/Desktop/Website/ColoredLists_v1.0');

However, if I want to do this for all my scripts, I can't seem to make the change permanent. Even after I edited the Unix include_path in my php.ini, it doesn't seem to work.

UPDATE: I finally decided that the easiest sureshot way was to run the Apache server locally. It comes preinstalled with Mac, so didnt face much trouble there. I modified the httpd.conf to only allow connections from localhost, thus alleviating my security fears. Ofcourse, this still opens up port 80, but I'm behind a router, so I'm gonna hope I'm not very exposed. And Coda includes a great features in 'Sites', where I can set the local url, so it works brilliantly now. Only downside is, now, after code edits, I need to manually refresh the preview.

Comment: What do you mean working from "file" and "not from server"? Command line instead of Apache?

Comment: Yes @zneak. The PHP files are just processed from the file by PHP, and then the output html file is rendered in a browser. The request doesn't go to a server, request a page, and then return the rendered html. So theres no question of htaccess or apache config here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this method.

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/example.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
set_include_path(
    '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/neil/Desktop/Website/ColoredLists_v1.0' .
    PATH_SEPARATOR . 
    get_include_path());
```

in a shared include file

or edit your php.ini and change the include_path variable (I'm using MAMP so can't tell you the exact path to php.ini)

Answer (score 0):

It truly is an include_path issue. The default seems to be `.:/usr/lib/php`; perhaps if you launched the PHP command from the directory in which are your scripts, it would be fine?

Answer (score 0):

this works every time for me:

`<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/common/header.php'); ?>`

Comment: I don't think any of the $_SERVER variables will work, considering its running PHP off of commandline, not a server. I dunno. I'll still try it out later.